# Back to url after add/edit object in Django app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

What is the best approach to implement back action to the url, after add/edit some objects in Django app? In my application I have implemented views to add/edit objects, which could be launch from many places (many different paths to the same action). Now I want to improve my app, and introduce functionality to back user after closing add/edit form to exactly the same place which he was before launching the form.
Is any common practice to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple way to accomplish this is just by give your form an hidden input called **`next`**, then at the `views` just `redirect` user to **`next`**'s value.

It's the way of [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django%20redirect%20next) of times already, you can either use the next parameter in your forms or, if you're using class based views, you could use the FormView's [get_succes_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) method to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that i get ur question clearly ;

but if you mean  redirect user to previous page where he was before goes to add/edit form ;

you can simply use javascript codes. sth like:

```
history.back(-1)
```

this takes user to previous page on browser.